# Is Turbo decoding modulation dependent?

Tags: modulation, digital-communications, decoder, digital-modulation, encoding

I want to use the BER result of a turbo coded system from an article, but my system is not BPSK (and the article has discussed just the BPSK case). Now I wonder is Turbo decoder, modulation dependent?

Comment: Please provide a link to the article.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you can use Turbo Coding on top of any modulation scheme.

Comment: Yes I know that I can use Turbo codes independent from the modulation scheme, however the figures of merit for a specific Turbo code that follows two different modulation scheme can be different, hence if you want to use the data from an experience, then it must have the same modulation as your modulation. It is what I think (as the decoding for Turbo code is soft not hard). Feedback me if I am wrong

Comment: I've only used turbo codes with hard decisions and small constellation phase amplitude modulation, where modulation scheme really makes very little difference.  However, I would guess that if you used something like a large mulit-level FSK, where the p(error) for each bit can be significantly different, then yes, the performance characteristic could change materially.